# Android - Find out what hour of day it is

Tags: android, time, intervals, alarmmanager, hour

I want to use and alarmManager that sets a repeating alarm to go off on the hour, every hour. I know how to set a repeating alarm every hour but not how to actually set it from the top of the hour, I need to know this value for the 'whatTime' variable below.

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, whatTime, 1*60*60*1000, operation);
```

Also I want to be able to set a flag that for e.g. - if the time happens to be between 4 and 8 in the daytime, perform some operations, otherwise don't bother.
So I really need to know how to find out the hour of the day, can anyone tell me how to do this? Many thanks

Comment: How did you manage to set a repeating alarm every hour? How to do that?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try:

```
int hour = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

- [Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY) gives you the 24-hour time.
- [Calendar.HOUR](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR) gives you the 12-hour time.

Comment: That sorts the second thing I want to use it for and pretty sure it should work for my alarmManager too if i get Calendar.MINUTE I can work out how long til the next top of hour and set repeating alarms from then, thanks a lot man!